# AuthenticationManger in Spring security webflux

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to build a custom authentication manager for my spring-webflux app. However I find that my manager is never called. My code below:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().disable()
            .securityContextRepository(webSessionServerSecurityContextRepository())
            .addFilterAfter(new AuthenticationWebFilter(bearerTokenAuthenticationManager()),
                    SecurityWebFiltersOrder.REACTOR_CONTEXT)
            .build();

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you putting this bean?

Comment: The bean is a SecutrityConfiguration class annotated with @EnableWebFluxSecurity

Comment: Have you put this annotation - `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity` in the config class? And how are you checking your manager never gets called?

Comment: I am debugging and looking at the logs and I see that the manager is never called. I dont really need method security at this point-  I am not sure what 
 @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity will do to help. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you put this bean in a class annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` your problem seems that you didn't disabled `csrf` that is configured by default by Spring Security.

You can do that with the following:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable() // Disable csrf
            .securityContextRepository(webSessionServerSecurityContextRepository())
            .addFilterAfter(new AuthenticationWebFilter(bearerTokenAuthenticationManager()),
                    SecurityWebFiltersOrder.REACTOR_CONTEXT)
            .build();

}
```

Furthermore, you have to configure correctly the `AuthenticationWebFilter`.

An `AuthenticationWebFilter` has the following dependencies:

[image: AuthenticationWebFilter Dependencies]

...most of them are provided by default as HttpBasic deps (copy and pasted from Spring Security source code):

```
private final ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> authenticationManagerResolver;

private ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler = new WebFilterChainServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

private ServerAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter = new ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter();

private ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler = new ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler(new HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint());

private ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance(); // Stateless session

private ServerWebExchangeMatcher requiresAuthenticationMatcher = ServerWebExchangeMatchers.anyExchange();
```

You could set whatever you want with the setters method of `AuthenticationWebFilter`. An `AuthenticationWebFilter` has the following logic:

[image: AuthenticationWebFilter flow]

So depending of the case you have to configure one dependency or another. You could see a complete example of how Authentication and Authorization works in my repo: https://github.com/soasada/kotlin-coroutines-webflux-security (is in kotlin but for the case is the same)

Comment: Thank you! This helps